# How to assign values to store gender information?

Tags: database, data-structures

I'm creating an application that stores some data about users. I was wondering which mapping of the gender is appropriate:

```
male - false; female - true
```

or

```
female - false; male - true
```

Is there any standard for this?

Comment: I reckon strongly that there is no standard but most common practice is male = true and female = false.

Comment: For more information you can read this description [Male/Female Gender][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005681/what-is-the-convention-to-use-boolean-for-gender-in-programming-languages-true

Comment: I would say that you should not store this as a boolean value. You should always cater for "unspecified" as well.

Comment: @mydoghasworms in some databases the default boolean type is nullable, making it a boolean in name only but at the same type making it appropriate for the situation at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen the `bit` (SQL Server) type being used for genders, just as you mentioned. Some places where I've worked also used a `char(1)` column for that, because they thought someday they might also have to store genders other than male and female (i.e.: androginous/assexual, transexual (both originally male or female), hermaphrodite, unknown etc.). And who knows? In any case, both solutions work. I'm slightly inclined to say that the `bit` solution may have better performance if scalability is an issue, though it should only matter for really huge databases.

Comment: And there's XXY, XXX and XXXX - technically neither male nor female

Comment: That's off topic, but being really pedantic (and speaking generally of mammals), if you have at least one Y you're male. Otherwise you're female.

Answer (score 7):

I got it, it's a visual thing ;)

```
1 is for male
```

and

```
0 is for female
```

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge there is no specific defined standard for that.Some people use `M` and `F` and some will use `true` and `false`

Comment: I would say a designated key with values like "M" and "F" (and "U") is actually the best, as there is nothing true or false or numeric about any gender.